# how to change spacing in r bookdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, bookdown

Could you please help me adjust the spacing in r bookdown.

The bookdown guide is very vague about it and I could not find anything concrete.

Here is my YAML:

```
title: "Title"
author: "Nxxx"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
documentclass: book
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
```

Could you please show me how to change spacing to double.

Thank you in advance

This question is NOT a duplicate of this:
[Change line spacing for RMD abstract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118202/change-line-spacing-for-rmd-abstract)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change line spacing for RMD abstract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118202/change-line-spacing-for-rmd-abstract) This Q&A does even more than asked.

Comment: Ralf Stubner, dont you think i would have seen other similar questions before posting mine? If you think that the answer that you pointed me to "answers my question and even more", could you please explain how do i change the spacing for my particular YAML. Thank you

Comment: I see. You are only interested in HTML output. In that case search for "CSS double spacing" and look at https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html for how to use a custom CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer to my own question:

If you are like me and just started with bookdown, you are likely to follow the bookdown quick start guide where it tells you to clone the start repo from github.

Inside of that repo there is a style.css file.

Just go in there and add this: p {line-height: 2em;}

Working with YAML didnt really do anything. I didnt really have hours to figure this out. This is the quickest solution i think. Especially if you are new to bookdown.

Formatting in an essential part to writing a book or a blog and i think the bookdown authors should really work on that part in their documentation if they want more people to use it.